# How to get multiple selected elements at once

Tags: ckeditor

Probably a quite dumb question but still.

How do I get multiple elements which may be partially selected to wrap them with a new one?

**Example**: user created an H3 and then an ul afterwards. Then he wants to wrap it with colored div. He selects the ul and H3 text and hits the plugin button. How do I get all DOM elements affected with selection assuming user does not select all entire html but only a part of it?

I guess it's about

```
editor.getSelection().getRanges()
```

but I can not manage to figure the proper way out.

Comment: You should provide a code sample

Comment: @David not sure I can get what code do you mean. I've got dialog code, Ive got plugin code. They work so no need to provide it here. If I use mentioned before `getRanges()` I can not clearly understand what should I do next.

Comment: There is a `getStartElement()` method which returns the first element of the selection. But I can't see any kinda `getAllElements()` or similar to have an array of all elements within a range. I think there should be some method to expand selection so it can include entire elements but I can't see any in docs. I believe I have to 1. find some bounds defined by existing elements 2. expand selection for those bounds 3. put this inside newly created div.